# Routing data through two PPPoE accounts on one adsl line. Possible? (DD-WRT)

Tags: networking, routing, dd-wrt

I've been searching for a couple of days now, and have found many variants of my question but none that explicitly answer it. I've also made sure to go through the questions posted here to not create a duplicate.

My current configuration is a Netgear DGN3700v2 running as primary in the study connected to my PC, from there I have a cat 5e network cable running to my Dlink DIR 615 which is flashed with the latest build of dd-wrt as my secondery. All devices connected to the Dlink runs through HMA PPTP.

So my question is, is it possible to run one PPPoE account on the dd-wrt router and a different PPPoE account on the Netgear? I'm under the impression I must use the PPPoE Relay function under the services tab of dd-wrt but after flashing the latest build this option isn't available anymore.

I've set the Dlink to PPPoE entered the details, connected it to my netgear from a lan to wan (as it always was) but the dlink does not show a wan IP but funny enough on the netgear I can see the dlink connected under connected devices.

Please any pointers into the right direction will be immensely appreciated.

TL;DR Trying to connect Dlink (DD-WRT) router with 1 PPPoE account and Netgear DGN3700v2 with another PPPoE account on same ADSL line.

Comment: So, in essence, you're trying toc onnect to two different ISPs over the same ADSL line... if so then, I believe, this can't be done.

Comment: Hi Chris, I've read a lot of articles about creating PPPoE dial up connections in windows on different computers with different account details. So one would not be able to do this concurrently? Also I'm aware of people routing their data using software though separate accounts for international as well as local data.

Comment: [__Although traditional PPP is a peer-to-peer protocol, PPPoE is inherently a client-server relationship since multiple hosts can connect to a service provider over a single physical connection.__](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol_over_Ethernet#PPPoE_Discovery_.28PPPoED.29) How to do it and if it is possible with 2 different providers is a different question ;)

Comment: Is one router plugged into the other?